# jQuery/Javascript animation changing css value on interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created several div-elements under class name "image-part" and am trying to animate them using this script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.image-part').each(function() {
    var id = setInterval(frame, 3000);

    function frame() {
      if ($(this).css("visibility") === "hidden") {
        $(this).css("visibility", "visible");
      } else {
        $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.image-part {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-part" style="visibility:hidden"></div>
<div class="image-part"></div>
<div class="image-part"></div>
<div class="image-part"></div>
```

Nothing is happening, is there anyone that can help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because the scope of `this` within the `setInterval()` handler will not be a reference to any of the `.image-part` elements.

To fix this you can re-arrange the logic so that you execute the `each()` loop *within* the interval, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.image-part').css('visibility', function(i, v) {
      return v == 'visible' ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
    });
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
.image-part {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-part" style="visibility:hidden"></div>
<div class="image-part"></div>
<div class="image-part"></div>
<div class="image-part"></div>
```

Note that I changed the logic to be more succinct by using a single call to `css()` with a function provided. The outcome is identical to your original intention, though.